# Remove all custom key bindings/Reset key bindings to default

Tags: key-bindings, init-file

I don't know Lisp unfortunately. I have a friend, and I really liked his color scheme/default Emacs setup. However, I hate his hotkeys and I am used to the ones that come as default with Emacs. Is there any relatively painless way to go into the .emacs file that he gave me and basically just remove *only* his key bindings/hotkeys but keep all the visuals the way he has them? Again, please excuse my ignorance and frankly I usually get Emacs to "just work" to the point where I rarely actually have to edit the Lisp. **By the way, I'm on Fedora 25.** Thank you.

Comment: Going into the configuration section but it appears as if a reset might overwrite all of my settings.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to bind keys and change keybindings.  Look through the [Emacs manual on keybindings](https://www.google.com/#q=emacs+manual+keybindings) to see how to do so, and that can help you identify which lines you should comment out (or remove) from the `.emacs` file you have.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just wanted to check and make sure that would be the best way. In the past, I've tended to go and spend a week on something only to have someone say "Oh you could have just done xyz" lol!

Comment: What @Dan suggested is a good idea: read about how key bindings are set, so you can recognize where this is done in your friend's code. You might also ask your friend... It's hard to know just what to tell you, as your friend's setup (code) is completely unknown here.